# Idea plugin depend on other modules

Tags: plugins, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I'm developing my idea plugin, using gradle as my building tool. It's a multi-module project, which contains some normal modules(not plugin). For these normal modules, I can easily using `implementation` depend on other normal modules.
Just like this:
`implementation project(path:':plugin')`
But for the plugin module, it seems that `implementation` really doesn't work, my plugin module can't attach other modules at all.
Here is my project structure below:
`project | ------normal_module_1 |        | |        ... ------normal_module_2 |        | |        ... ------plugin_module | ...`

Any answer will be helpful for me!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's great to have you here. However, your question might benefit from some improvements. Could you provide more context and be more specific about your issue? This will help you get better responses. Please read following guide: [How To: Write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Afterwards [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) your post and improve it. Happy coding!